# Why does this program always return "None" at the end of it?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def ticketdo(tickethave):
    phrase = "Your total is $"
    if tickethave == "n":
        print phrase + "22"
    elif tickethave != "n":
        tickethour = input("How long has your car been parked?")
        if tickethour <=1:
            print phrase + "2"
        elif tickethour <=2:
            print phrase + "4"
        elif tickethour <=3:
            print phrase + "6"
        elif tickethour <=4:
            print phrase + "8"
        elif tickethour <=5:
            print phrase + "10"
        elif tickethour <=6:
            print phrase + "12"
        elif tickethour <=7:
            print phrase + "14"
        elif tickethour <=8:
            print phrase + "16"
        elif tickethour > 8:
            print phrase + "20"

def main():
    tickethave = raw_input("Do you have your ticket? (y/n): ")  

    print ticketdo(tickethave)

main()
```

Comment: Please use a code block to make this code more presentable.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `ticketdo` doesn't return anything.  Functions that don't return anything return `None` by default.  This is because, in Python, all functions must return *something*.

Furthermore, by doing:

```
print ticketdo(tickethave)
```

you are telling Python to print the return value of `ticketdo`.

So, to fix the problem, drop the `print` on that line or have `ticketdo` return something and then print that (judging by your code structure, you will probably want the first solution).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the return value of your `ticketdo` function. Since you didn't explicitly specify a return value for that function, it will automatically return the default value which is `None` and  that is exactly what you are printing to stdout.

If you want to simply call the function without printing its return value, just do:

```
ticketdo(tickethave)
```

You don't need to do anything with the return value of a function when you call it. Using the return value is entirely optional.

Answer (score -1):

I just remove print before `ticketdo(tickethave)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ticketdo(tickethave):
    phrase = "Your total is $"
    if tickethave == "n":
        print phrase + "22"
    elif tickethave != "n":
        tickethour = input("How long has your car been parked?")
        if tickethour <=1:
            print phrase + "2"
        elif tickethour <=2:
            print phrase + "4"
        elif tickethour <=3:
            print phrase + "6"
        elif tickethour <=4:
            print phrase + "8"
        elif tickethour <=5:
            print phrase + "10"
        elif tickethour <=6:
            print phrase + "12"
        elif tickethour <=7:
            print phrase + "14"
        elif tickethour <=8:
            print phrase + "16"
        elif tickethour > 8:
            print phrase + "20"

def main():
    tickethave = raw_input("Do you have your ticket? (y/n): ")  

    ticketdo(tickethave)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```